# Xamarin Preview window show android layout decorations

Tags: xamarin, interface, preview

I just found out how to get Xamarin's Preview Window working (gave several errors earlier) and it's great since I worked with Android Studio before which has a live preview. However, I can't seem to find how you show the statusbar, etc. (the "Show Layout Decorations" option in Android Studio). Is there a similar option in Xamarin?

Comment: Xamarin Forms previewer or Xamarin Android Designer? Because your question is ambiguous

Comment: I'm talking about the Xamarin Preview Window you can open from Xaml files.

Comment: If you want the Xaml previewer to show you how your android axml looks its not possible

Comment: could you show the screenshot of preview now and the effect you want  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be clear: You cannot have a simular effect of AndroidStudio's `Show Layout Decorations` in the Xamarin preview window.